# Filtering files with python

Tags: python

I generated data from the `netstat -a` command in the terminal, now from there the result is all the incoming and outgoing ip addresses which I wrote to a file, how to I retrieve only the ip address via columns?

Also, how do I retrieve data by column parameters? For example, starting at column 10 and ending at column 27.  I have tried the filter function but it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: http://sscce.org/

Comment: I assume that you've already tried `[line.strip().split()[n:k] for line in open('filepath')]`, so you really need to post some examples of what's going on, as @Marcin has requested

Comment: With awk `awk '{for (i = 10; i < 28; i++) print $i}' data.txt` this would be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the same as Levon's answer, but slightly more compact and Pythonic, and with the numbers adjusted to a guess at what I suspect the OP is trying to do.

```
with open('data.txt') as inf:
  for lc, line in enumerate(inf):  # lc - current line count
    if lc >= 2: # netstat usually has 2 lines of header info
      print ' '.join(line.split()[3:5]) # cols 3-4 are the addresses
```

Comment: It would have been useful to have access to the netstat output .. so I just had to guess on header lines, and use OP's example columns of 10 - 27 .. oh well :)

Comment: @Levon: Well, I just ran "netstat -a > data.txt" to get access to "typical netstat output". What kind of system are you on that has neither POSIX netstat nor Win32 netstat?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
with open('data.txt') as inf:
    for lc, line in enumerate(inf, 1):  # lc - current line count
        if lc > 3:  # if you need to skip some header lines ?? (unknown data)
            cols = line.split()
            for i in xrange(10, 28):  # print column 10 - 27
                print cols[i], '  ',
            print
```

It would be helpful if you could *post some of the data* with the question, so  in lieu of that *I am using your example columns of **10** - **27***.

Comment: +1, since it seems to answer exactly what the user is asking for. But why do the `for i in xrange` loop instead of just `' '.join(cols[10:28])`?

Comment: @abarnert I went with the loop so that OP has more options with formatting their output with individual withs/labels using `%`-formatting or with `.format`, and also have the ability to add labels etc. Otherwise, yes, the `join()` is a great way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = ...
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    for row in f.readlines()[1:]:
        columns = row.split()
        if len(columns) > 2:
            print row.split()[1]
```

Comment: `Netstat output is white-space delimited`. Don't need `csv` for that. `str.split()` should do the job. Or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Fixed. I originally started with `csv` because I thought it could handle variable white-space delimiters. `str.split()` is simpler.

Comment: It gives me an error object has nor attirbute '__getitem__'

Comment: `split(' ')` is not the same as `split()`

Comment: It says List Index out of Range [print col[i]]

Comment: @user1532695 the List Index issue should be fixed now